# Ionic: compileSdkVersion is not specified

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run the following command:

`ionic cordova run android --device`

But I am getting the following error

```
    BUILD FAILED in 3s
    (node:3956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: compileSdkVersion is not specified.
            at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:456)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:590)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$3(BasePlugin.java:555)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
            at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$4(BasePlugin.java:551)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
            at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
            at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:69)............
```

I tried removing and adding android platform

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

But still the same error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use **--device** to run the application on your phone you can simply use:

`ionic cordova build android`

and then

`ionic cordova run android`

and if you want to check the real result that everyone will see so the end result of the app that is

`ionic cordova run android --prod`
 but you can use that later for releasing the application.